# Getting List of Timezones in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, date, timezone, dst

I  am  able  to  get  list  of  timezones using

```
NSArray *timezoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames] ;
```

The issue  is  that  the  list  is  generated  based  on  the  current date  set  on  device. I want this  list  to  be  generated using a  future  date,  so  that  it  correctly  reflects  the  applicable  Daylight  Saving  Offset.

e.g. If  I  use  the  APP in May 2012  the  timezone  entry  for  Chicago is

> America/Chicago (CDT) Offset  -18000 (Daylight)

and  if  I  use  the  same  APP in  February 2012  the  entry  for  Chicago  is

> America/Chicago (CST) Offset  -21600

Can  I  change  the System  date  within  my  code  so  that  I  can  generate  the list  for  any  particular  date  at  will?

Sanjay